# Jenkins Pipeline plugin Linux error while running shell script

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a shell script using Jenkins pipeline plugin on a agent machine.
Below is the pipeline sample script:

```
 node("XXXXX"){
currentBuild.displayName = ''
sh 'XXXXX'
}
```

While running I am getting the error:

> Could not open 'getent hosts ent410373 2>&1|' : No such file or
>   directory

`ent410373` is the slave agent machine which is a linux host.

Is this error related to pipeline plugin? or machine?

Because I am able to run the same script on jenkins using execute shell script builder plugin.

Please help.

Comment: Could you add the exact script you are using? At least the *sh* part.

Answer (score 0):

Please compare PATH values for both cases:

```
echo $PATH
```